# Should I disable directory listing for wp-includes?

Tags: security

This is more of a personal question for my own curiosity.

One of my websites appears to be vulnerable because the directory listing (/wp-includes) is enabled. It’s not difficult to fix, however I’m wondering how serious actually is this if none of the files can actually be accessed?

If I click on basically any file, including user-meta and functions.php it either returns a HTTP 500 or simply shows me a blank screen. So how would a hacker actually benefit from accessing the directory if none of the files can be accessed?

Answer (score 0):

Not especially, though I would disable it for your entire site if you have the option as a matter of general best practice.

In a well maintained WordPress install, the contents of that directory aren't a secret, even if the directory listing is hidden.

**This is because you should never modify that folder, so it will always match the `wp-includes` folder in the WordPress download zip.**

Anybody could look at WordPress on Github and see the listing, or download the zip, and expect to find the same files in the same locations on your site.

Of course if someone did change their `wp-includes` folder, then directory listings are the last thing you should be worrying about, as that in of  itself is a serious security and maintenance concern.